# Convert series of lists into dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: python, dask

How do I convert a Dask series that contains lists of varying length into a dataframe with multiple columns? In Pandas it's:

```
import pandas as pd

ps = pd.Series([["a0", "a1"], ["b0", "b1", "b2"], ["c0"]])
print(ps)

# 0        [a0, a1]
# 1    [b0, b1, b2]
# 2            [c0]
# dtype: object

pdf = pd.DataFrame(ps.to_list())
print(pdf)

#     0     1     2
# 0  a0    a1  None
# 1  b0    b1    b2
# 2  c0  None  None
```

How do I achieve the same with Dask? I do not know length of the longest list beforehand.

Comment: For that it seems you would need to do `.explode().unstack()` but it's yet not implemented in dask, see https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/8245